# Обновить функцию абстрактного класса

Tags: php, ajax, ооп

```
 пример обновления функции

  get_random_user.php
  <?php
       $class = new Class();    
       return $class->getRandomuser(); 
  ?>
  отправка обработки
$("#read").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "/path/to/get_random_user.php"
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
      $('.userread').html(msg);
    });         
});
```

Пример, но не могу создать рабочий, правильный  файл обработчик get_random_user.php
Не выходит результат..

```
   abstract class Modules {

           protected $config;
           protected $user;
           protected $message;
           protected $banner;
           protected $data;
           protected $user_info;
           protected $friend;
           protected $twitt;

    public function __construct($db) {
    session_start();
    $this->config = new Config();
    $this->user = new User($db);
    $this->message = new Message();
    $this->banner = new Banner($db);
    $this->friend = new Friend($db);
    $this->twitt = new Twitt($db);
    $this->data = $this->secureData($_GET);
    $this->user_info = $this->getUser();
    }


    public function getRandomUsers() {
    $randomuser = $this->user->getRandomElement(3);
    foreach ($randomuser as $row) {
        $sr["random_id"] = $row["id"];
        $sr["random_name"] = $row["login"];
        $sr["random_avatar"] = $this->getAvatar($row["login"]);
        $sr["random_link"] = $this->config->address."?view=userdata&amp;login=".$row["login"];
        $text .= $this->getReplaceTemplate($sr, "userread");
    }
    $new_sr["items"] = $text;
    return $this->getReplaceTemplate($new_sr, "userreads"); 
    }
 }
```

class="userread" должен обновиться. Интересует get_random_user.php

```
<small id="read">Обновить</small>
<div class="userread">
    <div class="fit">
         <img src="%random_avatar%" alt="avatar" class="featured" />
    </div>
    <a class="name" href="%random_link%">%random_name%</a>
</div>
```

Comment: видимо надо $user = new class_name(); echo $user->getRandomUsers(); прописать внутри <div class="userread">

Comment: Что-то у вас дичайшая каша. В первом куске кода наперемешаны php и jquery. Внизу php с куском html-шаблона. Итого 4 куска кода связанных друг с другом чуть менее, чем никак. И при чем тут абстрактный класс кстати? Где он у вас?

Comment: Исправил . Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Абстрактнй метод нельзя вызвать, также нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса. Поэтому вы должны создать дочерний класс, внутри которого переопределены абстрактные или другие методы.

Пример

**Modules.php** - абстрактный класс

Допустим getRandomUsers() - абстрактный метод, поэтому мы не знаем как он будет реализован в разных дочерних классах, делаем просто заглушку. В дочернем классе переопределим этот метод.

```
abstract class Modules
{
    /**
     * @var array User names
     */
    protected $users = [];


    /**
     * Modules constructor.
     *
     * @param $arr
     */
    public function __construct($arr)
    {
        $this->users = $arr;
    }

    /**
     * @return string User name
     */
    function getRandomUsers()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

**User.php** - дочерний класс, расширяющий асбстрактный класс Modules

```
class User extends Modules
{

    /**
     * User constructor.
     *
     * @param $arr
     */
    public function __construct($arr)
    {
        parent::__construct($arr);
    }


    /**
     * @return string User name
     */
    public function getRandomUsers()
    {
        $random_max = count($this->users) - 1;
        return $this->users[rand(0, $random_max)];
    }
}
```

**get_random_user.php** - файл, к которому вы обращаетесь с помощью ajax

```
require_once 'Modules.php';
require_once 'User.php';

$user = new User(['Lilu', 'Bruce', 'Jean_Claude', 'Arnold']);
echo $user->getRandomUsers();
//напечатает LIlu
```

Comment: Сложный алгоритм. Вы не могли бы внести изиенения в сами классы.   С __construct($db) будет  трудно

Comment: @shamilshakirov здесь нет никакого алгоритма. Это основы ООП.